# Owin Web API. Set Autofac Lifetime Scope

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, owin, autofac

I have a Windows Service created using `Autofac` as `IoC` and I want to add to this Windows Service an API using `WebApi` and `Owin` as Self-hosted API.

I have been reading Autofac docs but I'm having a problem. It seems that Autofac is disposing lifetime scope on requests.

When request is done to one of my controllers the lifetime is disposed. This is not my wanted behaviour because my Windows Service is running more things as you can see in my Windows Service class.

**Windows Service class**

```
public class WinService : ServiceBase{

    private readonly IContainer _autofacContainer;
    private ILifetimeScope _scope;
    private Service _service;
    private IDisposable _webApi;

    public WinService(){
        autofacContainer = BuildContainer();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string [] args){
        _scope = _autofacContainer.BeginLifetimeScope();
        _service = _scope.Resolve<IService>();
        _service.Start();

        //Set created lifetimescope to Startup class
        Startup.LifetimeScope = _scope;
        _webApi = WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: "http://localhost:8080");
    }

    protected override void OnStop(){
        _service.Stop();
        _webApi.Dispose();
        _scope.Dispose();
    }

    private IContainer BuildContainer(){
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<Service>().As<IService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(typeof(SomeApiController).Assembly);
        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

**WebApi Startup class**

```
internal class Startup(){

    internal static ILifetimeScope LifetimeScope {private get; set;}

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder){
        HttpConfigurartion config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);

        config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(LifetimeScope);
        appBuilder.UseAutofacLifetimeScopeInjector(LifetimeScope);
        appBuilder.UseAutofacWebApi(config);
        appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Web API requires a per-request lifetime scope. This is required by the Web API framework because you can't use the same controller instance for handling multiple requests over and over - you *have* to dispose of the per-request scope.

However, the way you have it set up should work - it should create a *child* of the lifetime scope you provided, use that as the per-request scope, and dispose of just that request scope. It should not be disposing of the entire container until the application shuts down...

...which may be part of the challenge - I have not personally tried hosting a Web API app inside a Windows service, but if something is happening that is causing the app to stop/fail, that'll dispose of the lifetime scope that you passed.

There isn't enough here to determine if something like that is happening.

There also appear to be typos in the code (`UserAutofacWebApi` instead of `UseAutofacWebApi`) which makes me think this code has been somewhat edited from what's actually happening, maybe in an effort to remove company names or something, but reduces my confidence that the issue can actually be fully reproduced using the current provided snippet.

Thus, all I can say is - what you have there looks right, and it's very similar to the [self hosting example provided](https://github.com/autofac/Examples/tree/master/src/WebApiExample.OwinSelfHost), so if something is happening, it's happening in code you're not showing.

Unfortunately, that's about all I can offer. I won't have time to "iterate" over the question/code sample that might change and additional comments, so hopefully I've at least been able to give you something to look at.

Comment: Yes you are all rigth. I have done some debugging and the proble is that objects registered as InstancePerLifetimeScope are beeing created also on requests and them disposing. Maybe I can use PerMatchingLifetime to create them on my custom lifetimescope. Thats correct?

Comment: For original WebAPI there should be InstancePerRequest. Check into that.

Comment: I know, but I think my mistake was in using InstancePerLifetimeScope for classes that mus be running in singleton mode arround the lifetime scope created by me in the code. And when using WebAPi the WebApi was creating another lifetime scope per request. Thats the reason of use InstancePerMatchigLifetimeScope. To difference between requests and classes that must be created only once per application